# How can I simplify my boot-loader-chain into a single menu? (ubuntu windows)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mbr, bootloader, grub

I've installed Windows XP Proffesional, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 9.10. On every boot my system nags me with 2 menu´s.

1. Ubuntu Grub2 Bootloader (Ubuntu or Windows 7)
2. Windows 7 Bootloader (Windows 7 or older)

The Windows 7 runs of a virtual Harddisk located on the XP Partition. How is it possible to put it all into Grub2?

Comment: you can boot into win7 but it's installed to a "virtual harddisk" on the xp partition?  what??

Comment: @quack: I think some versions of Windows can boot from `.vhd` images, similar to Wubi booting Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to use the simple, not ugly looking Windows boot-loader to display a clean interface asking you for which OS to boot into. For example, my computer asks me one of the following on start:

Windows Vista
Ubuntu 10.04

If I don't press anything for five seconds, it boots into Windows. It has no clutter whatsoever. Follow the instructions on my blog [over here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fright-now-in-tech.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F08%2Fuse-windows-bootloader-to-boot-windows.html&ei=uvd0TKUww6txxfTN3gU&usg=AFQjCNHSiAxkXaB0lJEhFt43atVDIL1SZw&sig2=qjhEpxg6EQYwYdamnc81MA).